# Why is my Binding not working?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

This is silverlight code - but I guess that this will be same in WPF - 
I have this simple classes

```
public Class A1
{
      string str1;

      public string Str_1
      {
           return str1;
      }
 }

 public Class B1
 {
      A1 a1;

      public A1 A_1
      {
           return a1;
      }
  }
```

I assume that B1::A1.str1 have the value "my string".

Now in the XAML I have this

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="B1">
   <StackPanel> 
      <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=A1, Path=Str_1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In the the code ( xaml.cs ) i writing in the constructor this

```
  LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
```

( the B1 object is part of the xaml.cs file and the B1 is also not null and A1 is not null )

But ==> this is not working ... and the text of the textbox is not update with the text that is in A1 object.

Comment: Still not sure what you want to do exacty, can you show us your xaml too? Think you need to look into the Binding with a path

Comment: In debug - i see the B1 object that have A1 object and the str1 of A1 is with right string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using element binding but A1 is not a named element in the Xaml page.

You want `Text={Binding Path=A_1.Str_1}`

This means that it points to the Str_1 property of the A_1 property of the data context (your code behind class).

*Please note that TwoWay is pointless here as you have no setters on your properties.*

To do this properly (assuming your values will change and be required) you need to implement setters on your A_1 and Str_1 properties and implement INotifyPropertyChanged on both your class A1 & B1.

Comment: Can you please explain  ? - i want to make the binding to str1 - and the object that i have in  the xaml.cs is object instance of B1.

Comment: I was putting an example together as you wrote this :)

Comment: Thanks ! this work ! In what cases i need to add the "ElementName" ?

Comment: You use ElementName in *element to element* binding (e.g you want to bind a value from one control on a page to a property of another control)

Answer (score 2):

You can say `Text={Binding Path=A_1.Str_1, Mode=TwoWay}` I think that should work.

Also if you want to do two-way binding you need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) to let WPF know it has to refresh the UI after you updated the value in code.

GJ

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your class B1 must implement INotifyPropertyChanged [like this](http://www.hightech.ir/SeeSharp/best-implementation-of-inotifypropertychange-ever).

Then you should make a property proxy in your B1 class like this:

```
public string Str_1
{
    get
    {
        return a1.str1;
    }

    set
    {
        a1.str1 = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Str_1"); // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation method
    }
}
```

And finally update your binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Str_1}"/>
```